# ImagePicker causes reload of UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using iOS 8 storyboard with auto layouts. I have objects that are hidden UIViews to start and end up being visible. Whenever I go pick a video from my UIImagePicker and come back, all the objects turn hidden again almost like the UIViewController is being reloaded. How can I fix this? How do I stop the UIViewController from auto reloading every time another controller is shown like in this case a UIImagePicker.

Comment: Do you have the animation code inside viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with that. The view controller just reloads the views as if the auto layout constraints are being applied again.

Comment: How are you presenting the ImagePicker?

Comment: imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

Comment: [controller presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: what is 'controller' and why not self?

Answer (score 0):

Do you perform any view related show/hide inside `viewWill/DidAppear/Disappear` or `viewDid/WillLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: No I don't do any of that